Unresolved referencce pyspark in Pycharm using python interpreter from aws glue docker container
I have setup the AWS glue container to work locally on my etl jobs. The code can be run with no problem. However, Pycharm code analysis tells me that pyspark is not installed even though it is and the code runs fine.

However the pyspark library is added by appending the pythonpath with the path to the pyspark library inside the container. I believe this is the problem.
As you can see in the picture, the awsglue library is properly recognized even though its installation is also done inside the container via appending the pythonpath with the library path. In the case of awsglue, I have added a zip containing the awsglue library manually as external source in pycharm. I haven't done this for pyspark and I don't know where to find the zip in question.
Where to find those or what to do to enable code completion for pyspark in pycharm?

Does it work if you change the import from from pyspark.context import SparkContext to from pyspark import SparkContext instead? I saw your import looks different from the guide blog

While the alternate import is also valid (doesn't raise an ImportError), pycharm keeps telling me that the reference is unresolved.
